# Positioning / Changing size of Slide on fullscreen presentation using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I position and/or change the size of the slides on fullscreen slideshow presentation? (While running the slideshow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run()
    .Left = 277
    .Top = 128
    .Width = 380
    .Height = 290
End With
```

Didn't find a way to avoid "flashing" of first slide.